# radial distortion formula and inverse

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I try to project a 2D depth map on a 3D point cloud. But I'm stuck with the distortion effect due to the lens.

For this, I want to found the inverse of the radial and tangential distortion formula.
Here are the formula found on openCV: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html
[image]

I want to found x' and y' expressed in x'' and y'' instead of above

Comment: From your question it's not apparent why you need the formula. Can't you simply use [`undistort()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga69f2545a8b62a6b0fc2ee060dc30559d) function?

Comment: @zteffi when I use cv2.undistortPoint(), I got the following error: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\undistort.dispatch.cpp:472: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && src.isContinuous() && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F) in function 'cv::undistortPoints'

Comment: That assertion is pretty self-explanatory, just check if `src` (the first argument) has correct depth and is not empty.